# Make glob fetch files from logged in users directory

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to make glob fetch me all the mp3 and ogg files that are in /accounts/$username/clips folder.

```
<?php

$files = glob("accounts/"$username."/clips/"*.{mp3,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE) ?>
```

That's about what I've been trying with no luck, what is the correct way to define $username as the logged in persons username and write it into that code.

edit.

```
     require('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['username']` ? but really how would we know?

Comment: @nogad Exactly; all the more reasons I voted as unclear. OP's down in the answers area, if you wish to speak with them ;-)

Comment: I've edited original post with a piece of code

Comment: this isn't a live / functional site is it? you realize that that isn't safe at all

Comment: Plus, [the original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43507795/1) contained `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 2 Code` which doesn't support what you posted. So, the question IMHO is still unclear and as to the origin of the POST arrays.

Comment: No, I'm running this on xampp local server.

Comment: The session_start part was a bit off topic so i figured to delete that part, as I got is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if session has started via:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
```

Also you are missing concatenation character. Try this:

```
$files = glob("accounts/".$username."/clips/*.{mp3,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Can you share how you are setting `$username`

Comment: I deleted one `session_start();` line and it disappeared.
I can, if I knew which one to give to you.. my code is mainly copied elsewhere so its kind of messy.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make this work with the following code

```
isset($_SESSION['username']); 
 $files = glob("accounts/".($_SESSION['username'])."/clips/*.{mp3,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE)
```